# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - Wrong version number on Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I've been trying to run some automated tests with Capybara and Cucumber on a website hosted locally, on my machine. I can see the homepage when accessing localhost:3000, but whenever I type `cucumber` on my shell, I get `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`. 
As I am not handling this directly through Capybara, I'm not sure how I can fix this error or at least get the compiler to ignore the certificate. I tried fixing it by adding the arg `--ignore-certificate-errors` to the Selenium options on the capybara.rb helper

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      chromeOptions: {
        args: %w[start-maximized ignore-certificate-errors],
        'w3c' => false
      }
    )
end
```

But I still got the same error. Where can I change those settings for Capybara?

I just want to be able to run the tests, so a workaround wouldn't be a problem. Sorry if I didn't get it right, I'm a real rookie to Rails in general.

Comment: Have you tried with `'w3c' => true`?

Comment: Yes. Didn't really work out

Comment: I see lots of suggestions for something like `require 'openssl'`, `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` (which I'm aware is insecure), but I just can't find any line of code in Capybara or Selenium that handles SSL. Should I just create a new file? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Any resolution to this? Im running into the same issue.